# Rails 4 Name Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I started learning rails and ran into a problem. 
I have a table of "users" with name and other columns. I want search by 'name'

musicians_controller.rb

```
class MusiciansController < ApplicationController
  def newsearch
    @users = User.search(params[:search])
  end
end
```

newsearch.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag musicians_path, :method => 'get'  do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]%>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil  %>
<% end %>

<hr />
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><hr></td>
  </tr>
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><hr></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

user.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  where("name like ?", "%#{search}%") 
end
```

When I try to view the page I get the error message:

```
    Processing by MusiciansController#newsearch as HTML
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveRecord::Base#with_scope and #with_exclusive_scope are
 deprecated. Please use ActiveRecord::Relation#scoping instead. 
  User Load (15.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT
 1
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (name like '%%')
  Rendered musicians/newsearch.html.erb within layouts/application (15.6ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `musicians_path'
 for #<#<Class:0x00000006a3b118>:0x000000050a4a60>):
    1: <%= form_tag musicians_path, :method => 'get'  do %>
    2:   <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]%>
    3:   <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil  %>
    4: <% end %>
  app/views/musicians/newsearch.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_musicians_newsearch_ht
ml_erb__367792918_42364700'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've set up your routes correctly, the collection helpers are plural. You want `musicians_path`. And, since you're creating a record, you want `method: :post`, not `:get`.

I'm a little doubtful about your routes because typically `musician_path` would also exist if you'd set them up via `resources :musicians`.

Comment: He is not creating a record, he is trying to search for musicians, so he wants a collection filtered on some search-parameter. So using `get`  is perfectly acceptible. Furthermore he is using a special route to `newsearch` action.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show us, does not correspond with the error.

Without knowing the routes, I am guessing you have something like

```
resources :musicians do 
  collection do 
    get :newsearch
  end
end
```

But then the generated path-name is `musicians_newsearch_path` (plural!). You can easily verify the available path-names using `rake routes` in your console: the begin-part is the path-name (add `path` to get the function name).

#### Suggested improvement

Why not combine the index and search view? You will most likely want to search straight from the index, and not go to a separate page?

In your controller write:

```
def index
  @musicians = Musicians.search(params[:search])
end
```

in your model write

```
def self.search(query_string)
  if query_string.present?
    where("name like ?", "%#{query_string}%") 
  else
    all
  end
end
```

And in your view (!!!`index.html.erb`) you just need to add the search-form

```
<%= form_tag musicians_path, :method => 'get'  do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]%>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil  %>
<% end %>
```